# (fast) pairwise comparison of matrix columns whose elements have "a/b" format

Tags: r, performance, matrix, string-comparison, pairwise

I have a big character matrix (15000 x 150), and with the following format:

```
       A     B       C     D
[1,] "0/0" "0/1"   "0/0" "1/1"
[2,] "1/1" "1/1"   "0/1" "0/1"
[3,] "1/2" "0/3"   "1/1" "2/2"
[4,] "0/0" "0/0"   "2/2" "0/0"
[5,] "0/0" "0/0"   "0/0" "0/0"
```

I need to do pairwise comparison between columns and get the proportion of rows where

- neither string separated by `'/'` is equal (coded as 0);
- only one string separated by `'/'` is equal (coded as 1);
- both strings separated by `'/'` are equal (coded as 2).

The expected output for the above sample 5 x 4 matrix is

```
          0    1    2
A    B    0.2  0.2  0.6
A    C    0.2  0.4  0.4  
A    D    0.2  0.4  0.4
B    C    0.4  0.4  0.2
B    D    0.2  0.4  0.4  
C    D    0.6  0.0  0.4
```

I have tried using `pmatch`, however not able to do pairwise comparison to get the above output. any help is appreciated.

---

**Revised question**

Is it possible to exclude the values "0/0" between two pairs to get the proportions? i.e. when A and B are compared exclude when A=B= 0/0 and get the proportions for the rest?

Comment: yes it does have double digits like `10/12, 1/12, 12/1` etc

Answer (score 2):

This is what I could provide so far:

```
fun1 <- function (S) {
  n <- ncol(S)
  ref2 <- combn(colnames(S), 2)
  ref1 <- paste(ref2[1, ], ref2[2, ], sep = "&")
  z <- matrix(0, choose(n, 2), 3L, dimnames = list(ref1, 0:2))
  k <- 1L
  for (j in 1:(n - 1)) {
    x <- scan(text = S[, j], what = integer(), sep = "/", quiet = TRUE)
    for (i in (j + 1):n) {
      y <- scan(text = S[, i], what = integer(), sep = "/", quiet = TRUE)
      count <- tabulate(.colSums(x == y, 2L, length(x) / 2L) + 1L)
      z[k, ] <- count / sum(count)
      k <- k + 1L
      }
    }
  z
  }
```

It looks bad as it has a double loop nest written in R, but the innermost kernel is extremely efficient by using `scan`, `.colSums` and `tabulate`. The total number of iterations is `choose(ncol(S), 2)`, not too many for your 150-column matrix. I can replace `fun1` by an Rcpp version if you want.

```
## your data
S <- structure(c("0/0", "1/1", "1/2", "0/0", "0/0", "0/1", "1/1", 
"0/3", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/1", "1/1", "2/2", "0/0", "1/1", 
"0/1", "2/2", "0/0", "0/0"), .Dim = c(5L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
NULL, c("A", "B", "C", "D")))

fun1(S)
#      0   1   2
#A&B 0.2 0.2 0.6
#A&C 0.2 0.4 0.4
#A&D 0.2 0.4 0.4
#B&C 0.4 0.4 0.2
#B&D 0.2 0.4 0.4
#C&D 0.6 0.0 0.4
```

---

**Performance**

Ha, when I actually test my function on a 15000 x 150 matrix I found that:

1. I could move `scan` out of the loop nest for speedup, that is, I could scan the character matrix into an integer matrix in one go;
2. `scan(text = blabla)` takes forever, while `scan(file = blabla)` is fast, so it could be worth reading data from a text file;
3. working with a text file is sensitive to the format of the file so writing a robust code is tricky.

I produced a version `fun2` with file access, and a version `fun3` using Rcpp for the loop nest. It turns out that:

1. reading from file is indeed better (but we have to provide the file in "/" separated format);
2. Rcpp implemenation of the loop is rewarding.

I came back and posted them here (see [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51904194/2)), and I saw [user20650's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51904622/4891738) starting with `strsplit`. I excluded `strsplit` from my option when I started, because I think operation with string can be slow. Yes, it is slow, but still faster than `scan`. So I wrote a `fun4` using `strsplit` and a corresponding `fun5` with Rcpp (see [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51904194/3)). Profiling says that 60% of the execution time is spent in `strsplit` so it is indeed a performance killer. Then I replaced `strsplit`, `unlist`, `as.integer` and `matrix` with a single, simpler C++ implementation. It yields a 10x boost!! Well, this is reasonable if you think about it carefully. By using `atoi` (or `strtol`) from C library `<stdlib.h>`, we can directly translate strings into integers, so all string operations are eliminated!

Long story short, I only provide the final, fastest version.

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction("IntegerMatrix getInt (CharacterMatrix Char) {
  int m = Char.nrow(), n = Char.ncol();
  IntegerMatrix Int(2 * m, n);
  char *s1, *s2;
  int i, *iptr = &Int(0, 0);
  for (i = 0; i < m * n; i++) {
    s1 = (char *)Char[i]; s2 = s1;
    while(*s2 != '/') s2++; *iptr++ = atoi(s1);
    s2++; *iptr++ = atoi(s2);
    }
  return Int;
  }")

cppFunction('NumericMatrix pairwise(NumericMatrix z, IntegerMatrix Int) {
  int m = Int.nrow() / 2, n = Int.ncol();
  int i, j, k, *x, *y, count[3], *end; bool b1 = 0, b2 = 0;
  double M = 1 / (double)m;
  for (k = 0, j = 0; j < (n - 1); j++) {
    end = &Int(2 * m, j);
    for (i = j + 1; i < n; i++, k++) {
      x = &Int(0, j); y = &Int(0, i);
      count[0] = 0; count[1] = 0; count[2] = 0;
      for (; x < end; x += 2, y += 2) {
        b1 = (x[0] == y[0]);
        b2 = (x[1] == y[1]);
        count[(int)b1 + (int)b2]++;
        }
      z(k, 0) = (double)count[0] * M;
      z(k, 1) = (double)count[1] * M;
      z(k, 2) = (double)count[2] * M;
      }
    }
  return z;
  }')

fun7 <- function (S) {
  ## separate rows using Rcpp; `Int` is an integer matrix
  n <- ncol(S)
  Int <- getInt(S)
  m <- nrow(Int) / 2
  ## initialize the resulting matrix `z`
  ref2 <- combn(colnames(S), 2)
  ref1 <- paste(ref2[1, ], ref2[2, ], sep = "&")
  z <- matrix(0, choose(n, 2), 3L, dimnames = list(ref1, 0:2))
  ## use Rcpp for pairwise summary
  pairwise(z, Int)
  }
```

Let's generate a random 15000 x 150 matrix and try it.

```
sim <- function (m, n) {
  matrix(sample(c("0/0", "0/1", "1/0", "1/1"), m * n, TRUE), m, n,
         dimnames = list(NULL, 1:n))
  }

S <- sim(15000, 150)
system.time(oo <- fun7(S))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.324   0.000   1.325
```

Oh this is lightening fast!

> Is it possible to exclude the values "0/0" between two pairs to get the proportions? i.e. when A and B are compared exclude when A=B= 0/0 and get the proportions for the rest?

This kind of adaptation is straightforward at C / C++ level. Just an addition `if` test.

```
## a new C++ function `pairwise_exclude00`
cppFunction('NumericMatrix pairwise_exclude00(NumericMatrix z, IntegerMatrix Int) {
  int m = Int.nrow() / 2, n = Int.ncol();
  int i, j, k, *x, *y, count[3], size, *end;
  bool b1 = 0, b2 = 0, exclude = 0;
  double M; 
  for (k = 0, j = 0; j < (n - 1); j++) {
    end = &Int(2 * m, j);
    for (i = j + 1; i < n; i++, k++) {
      x = &Int(0, j); y = &Int(0, i);
      count[0] = 0; count[1] = 0; count[2] = 0; size = 0;
      for (; x < end; x += 2, y += 2) {
        b1 = (x[0] == y[0]);
        b2 = (x[1] == y[1]);
        exclude = (x[0] == 0) & (x[1] == 0) & b1 & b2;
        if (!exclude) {
          count[(int)b1 + (int)b2]++;
          size++;
          }
        }
      M = 1 / (double)size;
      z(k, 0) = (double)count[0] * M;
      z(k, 1) = (double)count[1] * M;
      z(k, 2) = (double)count[2] * M;
      }
    }
  return z;
  }')

## re-define `fun7` with a new logical argument `exclude00`
fun7 <- function (S, exclude00) {
  ## separate rows using Rcpp; `Int` is an integer matrix
  n <- ncol(S)
  Int <- getInt(S)
  m <- nrow(Int) / 2
  ## initialize the resulting matrix `z`
  ref2 <- combn(colnames(S), 2)
  ref1 <- paste(ref2[1, ], ref2[2, ], sep = "&")
  z <- matrix(0, choose(n, 2), 3L, dimnames = list(ref1, 0:2))
  ## use Rcpp for pairwise summary
  if (exclude00) pairwise_exclude00(z, Int)
  else pairwise(z, Int)
  }
```

Using the example `S` in your question:

```
fun7(S, TRUE)
#            0         1         2
#A&B 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
#A&C 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.0000000
#A&D 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.0000000
#B&C 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.0000000
#B&D 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.0000000
#C&D 0.7500000 0.0000000 0.2500000
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses ideas from 李哲源;s answer, particularly the `tabulate` -- gives a wee speed up. For data 15000x160 takes ~14 seconds on my old laptop

```
# split strings and form matrix for each column
ap =  matrix(unlist(strsplit(m, "/")), nc=2, byrow=TRUE)
ap = split.data.frame(ap, rep(colnames(m), each=nrow(m))) # maybe a way to use array?

# get 2-way combination of column names
co = combn(colnames(m), 2)

# test equality of each matrix
ap = apply(co, 2, function(x) tabulate(rowSums(ap[[x[1]]]==ap[[x[2]]])+1, 3))

# output
data.frame(t(co), t(ap)/nrow(m))
```

data

```
m = as.matrix(read.table(header=T, text='       A     B       C     D
 "0/0" "0/1"   "0/0" "1/1"
 "1/1" "1/1"   "0/1" "0/1"
 "1/2" "0/3"   "1/1" "2/2"
 "0/0" "0/0"   "2/2" "0/0"
 "0/0" "0/0"   "0/0" "0/0"'))

m = do.call(cbind, replicate(40 , m, simplify = FALSE))
m = do.call(rbind, replicate(3000, m, simplify = FALSE))
colnames(m) =  paste0("A", 1:160)
```

Comment: Is it possible to exclude the values "0/0" between two pairs to get the proportions? i.e. whe n A and B are compared exclude when A=B= 0/0 and get the proportions for the rest?

Answer (score 0):

You can create 3 functions to indicate 0,1,2 conditions and then iterate over column names to have distinct pairs and apply functions to create resulting data.frame:

```
library(tidyr)
matrix <- read.csv("matrix.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
n <-nrow(matrix)
c <- ncol(matrix)
zero <- function(A, B){ res <- sum(!grepl("0", A) & !grepl("0", B))/n }
one <- function(A, B) {
  A <- unlist(str_split(A, "/"))
  B <- unlist(str_split(B, "/"))
  comp <-data.frame(cbind(A==B, c(1,2), id= sort(rep(1:n,2))))%>%spread(V2, V1)
  res <- sum(sum(comp[,2]+comp[,3])>0)/n} 
two <- function(A, B){res <- sum(A==B)/n}  

res <-data.frame()
k <-1
for (i in 1:(c-1)){
  for (j in (i+1):c){
    A<-matrix[,i]
    B<-matrix[,j]
    res[k,1] <- colnames(matrix)[i]
    res[k,2] <- colnames(matrix)[j]
    res[k,3] <- zero(A,B)
    res[k,4] <- one(A,B)
    res[k,5] <- two(A,B)
    k <-k+1
  }
}
colnames(res) <-c("G1", "G2", "0", "1", "2")
```